# Pass path of the file to the application through .reg file

Tags: shell, registry, contextmenu, windows-shell

I have a requirement where, I have a context menu entry of my application. When I click the option, the absolute path of the file which was right-clicked needs to be input to the application so that the application can use the path to carry out the process. 
How to achieve this objective? I have written .reg file to add Context-menu.
Now I want assistance in passing the path of the file to the application in this .reg file.

Please help.

Comment: Show the .reg file you have written.

Comment: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TDCT]

"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TDCT\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TDCT\Shell\cmd1]

@="Compress"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TDCT\Shell\cmd1\command]

@="c:\\program files\\TDCT\\TDCT.EXE %1"

Comment: In your reg file you use "Folder" key. It means your context menu appears only when user right-click on folder. If you want your menu to appear when user right-click on file you should use "*" or "AllFilesystemObjects" key.

Comment: Thank you.
BUt, how to pass the path of the file or folder?

Comment: %1 means that shell will pass full file or folder name to the application as argument. So just use GetCommandLine function in your program.